# When plotting a graph xlim() is absolutely ignored

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm plotting a graph, and would like to change the limits on axis.
But xlim/ylim are both just ignored.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(18,6))
plt.plot(list(range(array.shape[0])), array[:,1],'bo')
plt.ylim((0,0.0025))
plt.show()
```

versions of SW:

```
conda version : 4.7.5
conda-build version : not installed
python version : 3.6.8.final.0
notebook            5.7.8  py36_0
matplotlib          2.2.2  pypi_0     pypi
matplotlib-base     3.1.1 py36hfd891ef_0  conda-forge
widgetsnbextension  3.5.0  py36_0     conda-forge
plotly              3.10.0 py_0  
ipympl              0.3.3  py_0       conda-forge
ipyvolume           0.5.1  py36_1001  conda-forge
ipywidgets          7.5.0  py_0       conda-forge
```

array is a 2D `numpy` array with numbers between 0 and 0.01, where I use only second column

Since no one can reroduce the problem, I assume it is caused by widgets and packages I installed recently in order to enable interactive plots in jupyter-notebook and jupyter lab.

[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code works for me, the y axis ends at 0.025

Comment: Also cannot reproduce - can you include more details about what your doing? What versions of the software are you running?

Comment: I'm using Anaconda (updated recently), Ipython, Jupyter Notebook.
Also I've installed some widgets to render 3D-plots in the notebook.

Comment: please include synthetic data in your example.  My wild guess is that your array is really an array of strings, but its hard to tell if you don't supply the data.

Comment: Nope, it is a numpy array. Zeroth (first) column is datetime.date, the columnss 1-3 are np.float64
>>type(array[1][0])
datetime.date
>>type(array[1][2])
numpy.float64

Comment: That's wrong in the snippet (pic): plt.ylim=(0,0.0025)). Please remove the equal sign. It's correct in the text snippet.

Comment: @MarcelFlygare it doesnot work neither way. I've tried all possible combinations with equal sign, single/double brackets etc.

Comment: It works for me, I'll add an answer with code.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, here is same working sample code, little bit simplified. If the question is different, please specify again.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(18,6))
plt.plot(list(range(5)), [0.0020,0.0021,0.0022,0.0023,0.0025],'bo')
plt.ylim((0,0.0025))
plt.show()
```